# Pound sign is displayed as '｣' symbol in sent email, have header meta tag as charset=utf-8

Tags: php, html

The pound symbol in my php file when is sent by email is converted to strange  '｣' symbol.

I have tried many different solutions but none seems to work.

Have tried tying replacing '£' with &pound etc...

This is in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
$message .= "Price Each: £".$row_get['price']. "\n";  
mail($to1, $subject1, $message, $header1); // send the e-mail to customer
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check please documentation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an encoding problem. You're not seeing an UTF-8 rendering.

The £ symbol is encoded as 0xA3, but in the [MS932 encoding ("Japanese ANSI")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)), 0xA3 is the '｣' symbol you are seeing.

To properly set the encoding of the email, you will need to add

```
$headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

to your headers.

You should also double check that your file is correctly encoded in UTF-8. If you write the pound sign in MS932 encoding, that would be encoded as 65410 65379. Coincidentally, &#65379; is the same '｣' symbol (&#65410;&#65379; would display ﾂ｣).

If you want to learn more, this is more thoroughly explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22120295/5589942) by Jon Skeet (Java, but the root cause is the same).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
$header1  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header1 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to1, $subject1, $message, $header1);
```

Comment: Tried that also, but no joy.

Comment: Have just found out, the resulting email is displaying correctly on PC and its only Apple Mac that the wrong display.

Comment: I suspect Apple 'Mail' encoding to be at fault!